# Trigger N future downstream tasks in Apache Airflow

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-scheduler

My goal is to write a job which incrementally loads data from a source to a destination table, and then calculates a 7-day moving average on that data. My initial instinct is to split this into two tasks, one which loads a single day of data into a table, and a second which calculates a 7-day moving average and loads the result into another table.

How can I configure airflow to trigger the next 7 task instances of the downstream task `calculate_7d_moving_average` automatically when a single task instance of `load_day_of_data` is re-run?

[image: airflow_tree_view]

Comment: Could you state your specific question at the bottom of your post? I am having trouble understanding exactly what you are asking.

Comment: @Zack I rewrote the question, please let me know if it is easier to understand now.